# Unity fails to load with nvidia-current with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M

Tags: 11.10, xorg, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I am using NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M

default nvidia-current can only boot into Unity 2D, Unity fails to load.

I tried proprietary version (285) and it can't get into lightdm at all until I removed xorg.conf, even after that I can only get into Unity 2D as well.

Finally I tried the ubuntu-x-swat PPA and still, logging in with Unity only defaults back to Unity 2D.

With all 3 drivers running the /unity_support_test -p command gets me

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: unable to create the OpenGL context
```

What can I do to get regular Unity running?

Comment: See also [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969) for the background why your graphics cards fail and for solutions to run programs with it. However, Unity is currently not supported out-of-the box with the solutions provided.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same card and had the same problem. While nvidia doesn't provide support for optimus technology, which this card has, on linux, I did get unity 3d to work by just uninstalling all nvidia drivers with:

sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia*

After rebooting, I had fancy effects and all. I hope it works for you too.